# connect to github.com port 443 in AWS Linux instance

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to cloning the repository from GitHub. but it returning with error

> ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I configured the inbound rules like below
[image: Inbound rules]

and in the instance `sudo nano ~/.ssh/config` I configured like below

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

and

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

> ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection timed out

But still same error. could any one help me in this regard !

Comment: There is no need to enable inbound to clone a git repository. Can you check on the outbound whether all traffics are allowed?

Comment: thanks @Sarath. After enable the outbound with all traffic its working fine